# Ionic 3 Horizontal Scroll X not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

Im try to added Ionic `Horizontal Scroll X` but it's not work for me. please look at my code and anyone know why this is not working? Im try to add `<ion-scroll scrollX="true">` not working. please help me to fix my issue

Thanks

```
 <ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="height: 100px; width: 450px;">
        <ion-item >


          <ion-avatar *ngFor="let staff of master.staffList" item-start >
            <img src="{{master.masterStaffs.get(staff.id)['IMAGE']}}">
            <p class="addnew-user">{{master.masterStaffs.get(staff.id)['NAME']}}</p>
          </ion-avatar>

          <ion-avatar *ngIf="master.getRoleID() == master.adminRoleID" item-start (click)="addnewTeacher()">
            <img src="{{master.addNewTeacherImage}}">
            <p class="addnew-user-main">Add New</p>
          </ion-avatar>

        </ion-item>
      </ion-scroll>
```

Comment: Why you use so many *ngFor ????

Comment: One  *ngFor is enough

Comment: @Gurbela . that one is i was going to be testing. that is my mistake i forget  to remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set style of ion-item to `style="overflow-x: auto;"`

```
     <ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="height: 100px;">
        <ion-item style="overflow-x: auto;">

          <ion-avatar *ngFor="let staff of master.staffList" item-start >
            <img src="{{master.masterStaffs.get(staff.id)['IMAGE']}}">
            <p class="addnew-user">{{master.masterStaffs.get(staff.id)['NAME']}}</p>
          </ion-avatar>

          <ion-avatar *ngIf="master.getRoleID() == master.adminRoleID" item-start (click)="addnewTeacher()">
            <img src="{{master.addNewTeacherImage}}">
            <p class="addnew-user-main">Add New</p>
          </ion-avatar>

        </ion-item>
      </ion-scroll>
```

Comment: Sir. thanks for your valuable time and answer . your answer is work for me +++ and  you can take the bounty in next 22 hours

Comment: Not working for me.!